# Talend Date format error

Tags: etl, talend

[image]

In funded Field the date with shows in picture is #####,01-oct-06

so my question

In talend which date format i can use help me

Comment: Very little information provided to help, from where you are getting the data or how are you processing the data or are you writing the data to some place - these all would help. For talend date formats see this - https://help.talend.com/reader/EFG5MHoKPz3XmDb5KATJ8Q/50G3oqMCIkXcL7qJrjy_kg

Answer (score 0):

For me it looks like the typical excel behaviour. Enlarge the column and everything should be fine. 
Additonally you should use a editor (notepad(++) etc) to check your data/exports.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly. If you can just expand the date column in excel a bit bigger, you will see the date values properly.

By the way, the default date format Talend uses is `DD-MM-YY`